# CSRF and JSON APIs

Tags: csrf, rest, api, json

I was searching for an CSRF implementation for Express.js, and i found something that get my atention, in this post it says that a JSON API is nos vulnerable to CRSF attacks... is that correct?? is not possible to forge a JSON request to do an unintented operation in this case?

https://github.com/pillarjs/understanding-csrf#use-only-json-apis

Considering that the allowed encType for forms are **application/x-www-form-urlencoded**, **multipart/form-data** and **text/plain** it totally make sense...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11008469/are-json-web-services-vulnerable-to-csrf-attacks

Answer (score 5):

They are still susceptible in XSS attacks, `plain/text` JSON enforcement, and if the origin policies aren't set up correctly. It's been answered before on Stack Overflow, but not here really. [The answer on Stack Overflow can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11008469/are-json-web-services-vulnerable-to-csrf-attacks) but I'll summarize here for archival sake:

Forms are limited to two methods: `GET` and `POST`
Forms are limited to three content types: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data`, and `text/plain`

Since you're posting over content-type `application/json` you need to use `XMLHTTPRequest` submission which is locked down with Origin Policies(Same, Cross) so now it depends on the server.

However, if the form generates valid JSON but sets the content type to `text/plain` and the server doesn't check that then CSRF is still possible if all the server is doing is parsing the data without checking the content type.

So really it's up to the server to check the post request, only allow content-type `application/json` and use correct origin policies to prevent CSRF with a JSON API. Remember CSRF is always dependent on the server to prevent the attack.

Comment: In the case that side-effect ops require authentication (a valid session cookie), wouldn't the check for `application/json` content-type suffice? CROS requests do not include cookies. And in general, if you have CORS enabled with a json API, that's not an CSRF issue no?